# ExtJS viewport panel

Tags: extjs, panel, viewport, collapsiblepanelextender

I have EXTJS panel inside a viewport east region,

```
var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
    layout: 'border',
    id:'mainviewport',
    monitorResize:false,
    items: [{
        region: 'east',
        xtype: 'panel',
        id:'east-panel',
        header : false,
        headerAsText: false,
        title: 'east panel',
        collapsible: true,
        split: true,
        minSize: 305,
        maxSize: east_panel_width,
        margins: '53 0 0 0',
        cmargins:'53 0 0 0',
        collapsed: true,
        autoScroll: true,
        layout: 'fit',
        html:'<div id="abc" style="height:100%;overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;"></div>'
    }]
});
```

I dont want the title header so i gave the property **header: false, headerAsText: false** the title bar get hided, but i want the collapsible option for this. How can i get that collapsible function.

Is that possible to hide only the title text and the background css of that, without distrubing the collapsible panel extender option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Even with **header: false, headerAsText: false** you have an arrow in the middle of the splitter bar. It works as a collapsing control of the panel.

Comment: Hi peter.., i am not getting any arrow in my page.

Comment: @Shakthi: What version of ExtJS are you using? It's there in ExtJS 4.0: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout/border.html

Comment: But in our application, we are using extjs 3.0.3

Comment: @Shakthi: Hm, you can still double click on the splitter bar to collapse the region. It's not very untuitive, that's why they added an arrow in Ext 4.